# Issue while forming and URL and sending it

Tags: java, http, url

I need to hit an URL after forming it.Below is my URL after appending the `authtoken("authToken":"SyrEgyXlx18U0hpoZK3EqBa5LACIEC7BxrHj\/CDBv5I=")` .   The issue i am facing due the presence of \/ in authtoken. I am getting the below error . Is there any other way round?

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 144: http://imapi-qa200.blurdev.com/v1/um/verifysession.json?userid=b02947f3cc9f44d1b4b318a4306addc4-US&authTokenSyrEgyXlx18U0hpoZK3EqBa5LACIEC7BxrHj/CDBv5I=

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the backslah `\` escape the next character. If you want the backslash in your string as a simple character, you must write `\\` (double backslach prints only one backslash).

Answer (score 0):

you can use `java.net.URLEncoder.encode(String s, String encoding)` to encode your URL like the following:

```
URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8");
```

it will automatically encode your string and escape special characters for you